# Filtering a query in parse that the key is a pointer

Tags: php, parse-platform

Im a bit new to the php side of parse, mainly objective-c and swift but I need to write some code that I can query a column (not the objectID one) to return the results..

The column I'm trying to query is a pointer to another class.

Here is the very basic code I have which returns all the rows in the class and the pointers data with the include key, but I need to filter or get only the row/s that I'm looking for.

```
$query = new ParseQuery("ClassB");
$query->includeKey("ClassA");
$results = $query->find();
```

In the php sdk I see an option to use equalTo which has a key and a value to it so I tried the following code.

so I choose the column that was the pointer , and its objectid to hopefully only return those row/s that has that object id.

```
$query = new ParseQuery("ClassB");
$query->includeKey("ClassA");
$query->equalTo("ColumnNameX", "yjdyaGRWP7");
$results = $query->find();
```

Nothing was returned and a php error was spit out

```
'pointer field ColumnNameX needs a pointer value' in /var/www/parse/src/Parse/ParseClient.php:326
```

So im not 100% sure why I cant filter by a ColumnNameX using its objectID which is a pointer to ClassA..

Did I miss something in the PHP docs..

I mean ideally in mysql to just get that row I want would be

```
SELECT * FROM ClassB WHERE ColunNameX = yjdyaGRWP7
```

That would return me the row of data, I can use a Join of course to get some info from ClassA as well.

Any thoughts on what im missing or do I need to first query the Class A to get a pointer, then in the equalTo do something like ("ColumnNamX" , $pointerfromClassA) ?

any one have anyone point out what im missing or have a code example.. I have seen some that use the objectID but I dont have access to that.

Comment: What does the table schema for `ClassA` and `ClassB` look like?

Comment: I believe that you would need to pass the pointer object as the second argument to the `equalTo` method instead of a string.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to figure out what you do in the equalTo argument.. any thoughts or hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out one way to do this, not sure if this is the right way but it returns now what I want..

```
$query->equalTo("ColunNameX", array("__type" => "Pointer", "className" => "ColunNameX", "objectId" => "yjdyaGRWP7"));
```